# What is the difference between nesting and flattening in rxjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using redux observable and I'm a little confused about whether I should be nesting observables in epics or flattening them.

I have a simple epic that takes an action, fires off a promise and then waits for the result to fire another action with the payload.

This gets the job done...

```
export const stageTitleUpdate = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('projects/updateTitle'),
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap(
      ({ payload }) => from(later(2000, payload))
    ),
    map(res => fetchFulfilled(res))
  );
```

I can also write it like so and seems to produce exactly the same result...

```
export const stageTitleUpdate = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('projects/updateTitle'),
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap(
      ({ payload }) => from(later(2000, payload))
      .pipe(
         map(res => fetchFulfilled(res))
      )
    ),

  );
```

Is there any difference between the two? Is it just stylistic, or will writing this one way over the other trip me up in the future?

Comment: I digested this over the last day and I have a better understanding of what is going on thanks in part to bit.ly/2LHn3hG In case this helps anyone struggling with the same, all switchMap (and other Map type operators) are doing is merging their contents back into the outer stream. So if you want to format the response from the inner observable, or catch an error, before you merge it back then do that manipulation on the inner observable. If it makes no difference then its probably better to handle the sequence of operations on the outer observable because it makes things easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key differences i learnt is

`from(later(2000, payload))` stream is refer to as inner observable.

Both style are valid, however logical inner observable will let you contain the error in the inner scope and keep the source observable flowing instead of completing or throwing error.

Style1 - the entire stream will stop emitting if `from(later(2000, payload))` or fetchFulfilled(res) throws error even when you use `catchError` in the outer stream.

```
export const stageTitleUpdate = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('projects/updateTitle'),
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap(
      ({ payload }) => from(later(2000, payload))
    ),
    map(res => fetchFulfilled(res)),
    // this will complete your entire stream
    catchError(e=>of(e))
  );
```

Style2 - the source will continue to work if you catch the error in inner observable

```
export const stageTitleUpdate = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('projects/updateTitle'),
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap(
      ({ payload }) => from(later(2000, payload))
      .pipe(
         map(res => fetchFulfilled(res)),
         catchError(e=>of(e))
      )
    ),
  );
```

Having say that it still depends on your upstream and downstream tasks as well as what kinds of map process(mergeMap,switchMap,exhaustMap) in upstream.  Normally if you compose you stream naturally according to your business logic things will work ok. i.e

```
const task2=task21().pipe(map(()=>task22())
task1().pipe(switchMap(_=>
   task
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helps. Good question